# What is mtdd in top command in linux

Tags: linux, database, kernel

I am performing large set of operations on my **PostgreSQL** database and the command **mtdd**(3rd row in the screenshot below)

%CPU reaches 100% ... what does mtdd actually mean??? will my PC hang??? i observed that in my system monitor, the CPU memory havent increased.

[image]

**Note** :- the rows in the image above are from **top command in terminal**

Answer (score 3):

I am seeing this as well since the 27th of February on our CentOS 7 box.
Do you use sophos? We have sophos central and this appears to be related to it.

There are references to mtdd here: https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/124433#Configuration%20options%20to%20turn%20on%20mtdd%20debug%20or%20trace%20logging
https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/128014

Comment: When I see it eating up resources I have used `pkill -HUP mtdd` to reload the process